# text decryption in python with rijndael-128 / CBC256 algorithm

Tags: python, encryption, decode, rijndael

I want to decode some text from a database.
I know the texts are encoded with  rijndael-128 CBC256  algorithm.
The instruction to decode the text is to transform the text to base64 format first then use  rijndael-128 / CBC256 algorithm. I also have the key which is 32  bytes.

The problem is that when I decode the initial text with base64, I get an output like this :

```
{
"iv":"zv2rEAMi38LKD2FJlIeMMg==",
"value":"UnnuNWqoZIgiALa4IchFA4ReYcBYwIdtpQEefEmt\/ViEMgBVMhfCAydGo1tXVRAdNNRSfMm6VelGT5vORxTFM\/03t3id5f5RQaPxSQ1rDRsn2yGyANDLF04szC+FhvVXiW5SBVAEtpFe....."
}
```

As you can see IV is more than 16 bytes, this gives me an error when I want to decrypt the text, using this line of code:

```
aes = AES.new(input_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
```

the error:

> ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode

Please tell me what to do if you have any ideas.
Please consider that I should use the given IV and Value to be able to get the decoded text.
Thanks

I searched to see what I am supposed to do, but none of existing solutions worked for me.
I want a python code to decode texts using rijndael-128 / CBC256  algorithm after I decode the text using Base64 algorithm.

Comment: If you base64 decodes the iv: "zv2rEAMi38LKD2FJlIeMMg==",  it is exactly 16 bytes ..

Comment: But it is 24 bytes! Isn't it?

Comment: *... CBC256 algorithm ...* I've never seen the CBC256 designation in any context. And yes, you have to **base64-decode** the IV first, and the other values too.

Comment: If you have any samples I would appreciate it